# Add/update author for git-together

Tags: git, git-commit, author

How can I add or update the list of authors for my git-togther commit?
In my virtual machine (Red-Hat) I am trying to add myself as an author for git so I can add myself or other co-workers for my commits.

Comment: I solved this by modifying the list of authors in ~/.git-together